# How to retrieve values of deep associations over a certain period?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following models:

```
Company has_many :businesses

Business belongs_to :company
Business has_many :employees

Employee belongs_to :business
Employee has_many :votes

Vote belongs_to :employee
attr_accessible :score
```

From a company what is the best way to get all the scores of all the votes al all the employees that belong to all the businesses that belong to the company?

Would I use has_many through or create a query or use a gem?

And then how would I restrict the results to only show scores for the last 30 days / 1 month ago?

I've tried:

```
scores = self.businesses.employees.votes.where(created_at: Date.today.1.month.ago).pluck(:score)
```

I've also tried
    Company has_many :businesses
    Company has_many :votes, through: :businesses

```
Business belongs_to :company
Business has_many :employees
Business has_many :votes, through: :employees

Employee belongs_to :business
Employee has_many :votes

Vote belongs_to :employee
attr_accessible :score

@company.votes.pluck(:score)
```

I'm using postgresql

Comment: How do you store votes?

Comment: I store a score. Updated

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
Vote.joins(:employee => :business).where('businesses.company_id = ?', id)
```

to *get all the votes for employees in businesses that belong to current company* (id).

Edit:

To answer your followup question:

```
Vote.joins(:employee => :business).where('businesses.company_id = ?', id).where('votes.created_at > ?', Date.today - 1.month)
```

Comment: Thanks @murrekatt. I get a postgresql error when I try your solution: created_at is ambiguous. When I add vote.created_at it gives me the error missing FROM clause

Comment: What ruby and rails versions are you using?